# weak convergence to a constant means convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $Z_k$ converges weakly to a constant $c\in \mathbb R$. Show that $Z_k$ converges in probability to $c$ by only using one of the statements of the Portmanteau theorem. I think part $(ii)$ of the statement is given? And we need to somehow apply part $(iii)$ of the statement since $\{c\}$ is a closed set? Thanks for the help. I am not understanding what are $Z_k$ to be used here?

[image]

Comment: Regarding the last sentence: The random variable $Z_k$ induces a measure $\mu_k$ by $\mu_k(A) := P(Z_k \in A)$ where $A$ is a [measurable] set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu_k$ be the measure induced by $Z_k$, i.e. $\mu_k(E) := P(Z_k \in E)$ for any measurable set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Similarly let $\mu$ be the probability measure that puts all mass on $c$. We are given that $\mu_k \Rightarrow \mu$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Consider the closed set $A:=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : |x-c| \ge \epsilon/2\}$. Part (iv) implies
\begin{align}
\limsup_{k \to \infty} P(|Z_k - c| > \epsilon)
&\le \limsup_{k \to \infty} P(|Z_k - c| \ge \epsilon/2)
\\
&= \limsup_{k \to \infty} \mu_k(A)
\\
&\le \mu(A)
\\
&= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: @miosaki I applied (iii) in one of my steps above.